# C++ Assigning reference variable from passed in reference variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm attempting to avoid using global variables since I don't know how the code will need to scale in the future, so I want the ability to produce multiple threads with independent mutex. I'm attempting to pass a Mutex and a Conditional Variable into a class constructor.

Header File:

```
class Receiver {
private:
    std::mutex & _global_mtx;
    std::condition_variable & _global_cv;
    bool & state;
public:
    // Construct
    Receiver(std::mutex &, std::condition_variable &, bool &);
};
```

Code File:

```
/*-------------------------------------
    Construct
--------------------------------------*/
Receiver::Receiver(std::mutex & mtx, std::condition_variable & cv, bool & state){
    _global_mtx = mtx;
}
```

This is obviously causing issues since `_global_mtx` is already declared as a reference variable, so I'm not sure how to pass the reference from `mtx` to `_global_mtx`.

Also, I know that when declaring a reference you must assign it a value to reference (potentially a NULL) so is there a better way of handling this that what I'm doing?  I'm certain I'm not the first and only person to come across this need but I'm not sure where to look for answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

References cannot be default initialized. They have to refer to something. So you have to *initialize* `_global_mutex`. Do it in the constructor initialization list:

```
Receiver::Receiver(std::mutex & mtx, std::condition_variable & cv, bool & state)
: _global_mtx(mtx),
  _global_cv(cv),
  state(state)
{
}
```

The same applies to the other data members.

Comment: ditto with `_global_cv` and `state`

Comment: That worked!  I did not know about the constructor initialization list .  (I'm returning to C++ after a 5 year break)

Comment: @BayssMekanique Ah OK. Well, by the time you're in the constructor's body, all data members have been initialized, implicitly or explicitly. You can only modify them in the body.

Answer (score 1):

To me, your code looks somewhat confused and confusing.

In most cases, a mutex (and, if you're using one, the associated condition variable) should be associated directly with some piece of data. In other words: you have a piece of data that's going to be shared between threads. You associate the mutex with that data to protect it, so only one thread at a time gets access to the data.

That being the case, you generally want to design your class with an instance of the shared data, and a mutex and (if needed) a condition variable. You almost never want to create those separately, then supply them to the class as you're trying to do in your question. While you can fix the near-term (mostly syntactic) problem of initializing a reference by using an member initializer list, that's rarely the right answer.

In most cases, the right answer is for all of those to be members of the same object, and supply member functions that carry out operations on the member data, locking and unlocking the mutext as necessary to do so.

Comment: I agree.  One hurdle at a time though ;-) I will be removing the cv and renaming the global once I add the second mutex and actual data object.  This code was making sure I could do what I mean to.